# OWL: get Class from an existent Antology

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

How can I get an existing Class from an Ontology with the OWL-API? This is a fragment of my ontology:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:ID="StringDocu">
  <owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:Restriction>
      <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
      <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasContent"/>
    </owl:Restriction>
  </owl:equivalentClass>
  <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >String Docu</rdfs:label>
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Docu"/>
  <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="#URIDocu"/>
  <rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >This class concerns a docu with the content specified as common text.</rdfs:comment>
</owl:Class>
```

I start with this code:

```java
String ontologyUri = "http://mysite.com/my_ontology.owl";
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLOntology ontology = manager.createOntology(IRI.create(ontologyUri));
OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
```

and now I want to retrieve the `StringDocu` class. How can I get this?

Answer (score 2):

continuing from the code you showed in your question, you can get a direct reference to the class as follows (I assume that your class URI is "http://mysite.com/my_ontology.owl#StringDocu"):

```
OWLClass stringDocuClass = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create("http://mysite.com/my_ontology.owl#StringDocu"))
```

That gives you a direct reference to the class you are after and you can take it from there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is nothing but just another way to represent an iri. this class has no connection to the ontology, with the same success you can use IRI itself or even String. To retrieve an _existing_ classes from ontology need to use 'signature' methods or declaration axioms

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you all classes referenced in the ontology you loaded:

```
String ontologyUri = "http://mysite.com/my_ontology.owl";
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLOntology ontology = manager.createOntology(IRI.create(ontologyUri));
Set <OWLClass> classes = ontology.getClassesInSignature();
```

Then you can process/filter/find whatever you need on that set of `OWLClass`.

Comment: Hi WongiSeng, that is way too complex - all that will do is to give you all the classes in the ontology as a set. You can get a direct reference to the class by knowing its URI.